# Is there a way to allow a Chrome extension content script to violate mixed-content rules?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension which makes an AJAX call to a local http server. The local server is not https. My extension doesn't work when visiting an https site, because of mixed-content rules.

This is disappointing because I thought the content scripts were totally isolated from the main DOM, so these rules wouldn't matter.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make the request from the content script itself.

You can delegate that to a background page by requesting it [via Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Also, make sure you have [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) for your local server. It may even solve the original issue.

Comment: Thanks! What are "host permissions"?

Comment: host permissions don't help with the https issue. as a side note, looks like i don't need host permissions OR cors headers to be able to make a non-https localhost request from the plugin. although if i try it from the console, i do get the warning. I'll try the Messaging solution next.